# Optimalization task

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have problem with optimalization function to generate document TAX FREE.

I add order positions with : name, price, weight and numbers (count).

Like:

```
product = array();
product[0] = array('name'=>'product_a','price'=>32.00,'weight'=>5.23,'numbers'=>100);
product[1] = array('name'=>'product_b','price'=>22.00,'weight'=>2.23,'numbers'=>140);
product[2] = array('name'=>'product_c','price'=>12.10,'weight'=>3.03,'numbers'=>150);
product[3] = array('name'=>'product_d','price'=>5.12,'weight'=>4.03,'numbers'=>10);
product[4] = array('name'=>'product_e','price'=>52.22,'weight'=>5.13,'numbers'=>22);
```

No from this positions I have to generate the smallest document TAX FREE. In one document I can have sum weight max 50 and sum price 2000 (price is for one element. If I have numbers 100  result is 100*price).

So I need to implode position and generete new document with the smallest count.
When I use only 10 element (all are 100) I have to add 90 elements into next documents.

Could someone help me with this? What kind of Algorithm I should to use? Can someone told me step by step How do that?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ?

Comment: I tried sord individual position (when I have numbers 20 I change It as 20 positions with price, weight) Next I sort this data by weight and price. Next I  try to take the highest values and complement the smaller.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Are you trying to make packages where package `weight <= 50` and `price <= 2000`? What are order positions? Do you need to follow order queue or you can create packages randomly in order to have most effective package with products?

Comment: I have order like array (above). Next I need to create document (packages) with all order positions but I need to be most effective. I have to use all positions and  weight <= 50 and price <= 2000.

Answer (score 0):

First divide prices with respective weights.

Then sort them in descending order.

Choose biggest value and store the respective values of price and weight in different variables.

The choose second biggest value and add respective price and weight to the variables declared in above point.

Repeat step 4 until price is >=2000  OR weight >=50.